# Tags from head moved to body from Kohana generated html in Chrome

Tags: php, html, google-chrome, kohana-3.3

Why my generated site with Kohana framework (but I thik this is Chrome problem) contains tags from head in body? And all body is moved down .. It looks strange :(

This is output of Kohana after call url: `http://127.0.0.1/weu/Test`

```
<html lang="en">
  <head></head>
  <body class="container">

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My test site</title>


    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>My text</p>

</body></html>
```

My chrome version: 35.0.1916.153 m

It is chrome problem, or I doing something wrong?
Can I solve it somehow?
I just try firefox and it look ok (only html I writed to my site).

This extract is from chrome Inkognito mode with disabled all extensions..
[image: Meta charset inside body]

I use this route in *bootstrap.php*:

```
Route::set('test', 'test')
  ->defaults(array(
  'controller' => 'specialtest',
  'action'   => 'index',
  ));
```

This is my Controller *Test.php*:

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');
class Controller_Test extends Controller_Template {
public $template = 'simpleview';
  public function action_index()
  {
    $this->template->message = 'My text';
  }
}
```

and my view *simpleview.php*:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>My test site</title>
  </head>
  <body class="container">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p><?= $message ?></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

## Edit (problem simulated on Firefox)

Complicated site (my working project) looks strange also in Firefox.
You can see meta tag inside body also as in Chrome.

In this project I using Zurb foundation template + modernizer + jquery (but it was not used in test above as you can see)

Screenshot of firefox with DOM tree:

[image: Firefox]

This is start of site from firefox:

```
<html class=" js flexbox flexboxlegacy canvas canvastext webgl no-touch geolocation postmessage no-websqldatabase indexeddb hashchange history draganddrop websockets rgba hsla multiplebgs backgroundsize borderimage borderradius boxshadow textshadow opacity cssanimations csscolumns cssgradients no-cssreflections csstransforms csstransforms3d csstransitions fontface generatedcontent video audio localstorage sessionstorage webworkers applicationcache svg inlinesvg smil svgclippaths" lang="en">
<head><meta class="foundation-data-attribute-namespace"><meta class="foundation-mq-xxlarge"><meta class="foundation-mq-xlarge"><meta class="foundation-mq-large">
<meta class="foundation-mq-medium"><meta class="foundation-mq-small"><style></style><meta class="foundation-mq-topbar"><script src="//savingsslider-a.akamaihd.net/loaders/1036/l.js?aoi=1311798366&amp;pid=1036&amp;zoneid=92248&amp;ext=Slick%20Savings" charset="UTF-8" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body><!-- weustandard.php -->

<!-- html class="no-js" lang="en" -->
<!-- start.php -->

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Weu - systém pre evidenciu zaúčtovaných faktúr</title>
<!-- ZurbFoundationCss  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/weu/css/foundation.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/weu/css/foundation-icons/foundation-icons.css">
<!-- Modernizer  -->
    <script src="/weu/js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>


<!-- GOOGLE  -->
  <!-- script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).p.......
```

**You can see meta tag after first body tag.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same thing!

it turned out that one of the php files thats was included had been encoded with Unicode Signature (BOM)

i used this command in the base DIR of my site

```
find . -name "*.inc" | xargs grep -l $'\xEF\xBB\xBF'`
```

to find the files causing it & just changed the file encoding

Comment: thanks, set correct encoding for all files realy help me

Comment: In case others come looking for a windows alternative. This is what I used: http://www.mannaz.at/codebase/utf-byte-order-mark-bom-remover/